# In xcode 9 with iOS 11 - issue with loading of Map tiles on first run

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios11

--Updated with new findings -- Tested in both simulator and on device. Maps are not loaded correctly when the app is run from a cold start. Tiles are not being displayed.

`mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` is not being called. So something is going wrong for the map not to finish, but I am getting no errors.

The map is loaded fine if I just briefly go out of the app and then in again. Meaning that the maps are loaded if app is opened from background.

Any ideas what has change? Worked just fine in iOS 10.

[image]

**Update**

In iOS 11 `mapViewWillStartLocatingUser` is being called but not `mapViewWillStartRenderingMap`. I wondering if I have to manual call something so that the rendering off the map will be started. In iOS 9 (what I test against, and were it works just fine) `mapViewWillStartRenderingMap` is called before `mapViewWillStartLocatingUser`

Comment: Are you initializing the MapView in the viewDidLoad method in your view controller? If so, try moving it to the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Just tried that, but makes no difference. Also not something I would want, as that would ruin usability as the map would be reloaded to often.

Comment: Right now I am waiting it out to see if it will be solved in later beta versions. Else I will get back to trying to find a solution.

Comment: This is unfortunately still a problem in the new xcode version. @onmyway133 did you find a solution?

Comment: Is mapViewWillStartLoadingMap or mapViewDidFailLoadingMap ever called?

Comment: @Navillus No they are not called on first run. They are when I close the app and open it again.

Comment: @Christoffer I am also working on the map application but its working fine for me even on the first run of the app. Can you provide more information about your code? Also, are you creating the map in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @AkshaySunderwani I do not use storyboards. Have added a code example

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should try  By removing

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

}
```

and Putting following code into your View Didload Method

```
    CGFloat edge = 10.0f;

    UIImage *gotoUserLocationButtonImage = self.gotoUserLocationButton.imageView.image;
    self.gotoUserLocationButton.frame = CGRectMake(edge, edge + self.statusBarHeight, gotoUserLocationButtonImage.size.width, gotoUserLocationButtonImage.size.height);

    UIImage *getDirectionsButtonImage = self.getDirectionsButton.imageView.image;
    [self.getDirectionsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.gotoUserLocationButton.frame), edge + self.statusBarHeight, getDirectionsButtonImage.size.width, getDirectionsButtonImage.size.height)];
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. User location works and is also displayed on the "map". As you can see on the image above. Did you mean that?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. Can you Please Try Reloading map in viewWillAppear. Because apparently there looks no issue with it.

Comment: give me some minute i am trying it in demo.

Comment: I am unable to run it on demo as there is hell of dependency code. Unfortunately, But i am trying i find issue i will share you.

Comment: Yes sorry about that. It's a complex project :/ I have tried reloading the map with '[self.mapView setRegion:self.mapView.region animated:true];' in both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. But did nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154888/discussion-between-christoffer-and-abu-ul-hassan).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using dispatch_async for the map.

I had the following function that did not work in iOS11

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    @synchronized(_queue) {
        if(poppedMapView != nil) {
            [self.queue removeObject:poppedMapView];
        }
        [self.queue addObject:[[MKMapView alloc] init]];
    }
});
```

Changed it to

```
if(poppedMapView != nil) {
    [self.queue removeObject:poppedMapView];
}
[self.queue addObject:[[MKMapView alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem, spent a lot of time to find a solution and finally I did. So in my case problem was with wrong inisializing. Usually you would write let mapView = MKMapView() on the top of the viewController and then customise it somewhere later inside viewDidLoad but after IOS 11 Beta 1 it stopped working. I fixed it by changing to var mapView: MKMapView? on the top of the viewController and then inside viewDidLoad I inisializ it like mapView = MKMapView(). Hope it helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem my BROKEN code looked something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var mapView = MKMapView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add the mapView to the VC
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

As it turned out in iOS 11 it does not like having the MKMapView initialize before the view controller has loaded ie viewDidLoad() so FIX was changing to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var mapView: CSMapView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Init instance here.
        mapView = CSMapView()

        // Add the mapView to the VC
        mapView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ...
    }
}
```

Also tried putting it in init methods but this DID NOT work for me:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    mapView = MKMapView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    mapView = MKMapView()
}
```