# "[VKDefault] Tile in current unloaded state" iOS 11 map is not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, mapkit, ios11

I just create project and in my first viewController added `MKMapView` but what I'm seeing! Map is totally stuck means not able to scroll/zoom in-out and etc.

Is it Bug or doing any mistake to add Map in Xcode 9? Is there any additional setup required for latest system?

I did not write any code so here not adding my code.

Comment: Similar (without answer but with more attention): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049985/in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-issue-with-loading-of-map-tiles-on-first-run

Answer (score 1):

MKMapView is very sluggish in XCode 9... this is a known problem on Apple's side. If you want to see faster performance, use your mobile device rather than the simulator for testing. Be advised that XCode 9 doesn't work with iOS 11.1.2 at this point. Found that out the hard way.

At this point, my app doesn't require scrolling, but I am having to press and hold for about 5 - 7 seconds to get my pin to appear.

Fun times.